# Post-запрос в кодировке win1251

Tags: node.js, post

Добрый день.

Возможно, вопрос совсем легкий, но я потерялся в трех соснах.

Есть сервис, который принимает от клиентов post-запросы. Так получается, что сервис использует кириллицу и планирует работать в кодировке win1251.

Так вот вопрос, как сделать правильно POST-запрос, чтобы он данные в теле запроса были именнов нужной кодировке, а не в utf-8.

Сам запрос делаю при помощи node js. OS Xubuntu.

Comment: Если прямо не получается, то через костыли: завести массив с кодировкой и самому собрать буфер.

Comment: В 2017 нужны *очень* веские основания планировать работать в win1251 вместо utf-8.